# How to block user from going back when login screens appears, not killing the activity (Firebase Authentification)

Tags: android, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have designed a Splash Screen with its own independent activity (Splash Activity):

```
class SplachActivity:AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
    val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    if (user != null)
    {
        AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this)
        val startIntent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
        startIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        startActivity(startIntent)
        finish()
    }
    else
    {
        val providers = arrayListOf(AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(), AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build())
        startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .setLogo(R.drawable.ic_calculate)
                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                .build(),
            0)

    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if(requestCode == 0)
    {
        val response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data)
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {

            val startIntent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
            startIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
            startActivity(startIntent)
            finish()
        }
        else
        {
            if (response != null) {
                Log.e("LogIn Error","${response.error?.errorCode}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, this splash screen, while acting as a launcher, also acts as an activity that will bring user to login screen if the user is not signed in.

However, I am trying to prevent user from coming back to this activity (By pressing the back button because this activity has no layout). I tried the following:

```
        <activity android:name=".SplachActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:noHistory="true" android:excludeFromRecents="true">
    </activity>
```

But by doing this, the activity will be killed after navigating away, which results in onActivityResult() is never being called.

So I am not sure what I can do to not kill the activity but still prevent the user to come back to this activity (During login and after login), giving that I can't change the program of authentication as it is provided by Firebase.

Thanks!

Comment: Try this code for splash screen, you won't come back to splash screen

Comment: Handler().postDelayed({
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Start your app main activity

            startActivity(Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java))

            // close this activity
            finish()
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to disable the back button in short.

You can do it this way:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("Close Application?")
            .setMessage("Do you really want to exit?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                }
            })

            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Add this in your login activity. This will create an Alert Dialog instead of going back on clicking the back button just like shown below.

[image: screenshot of alert dialog]

Comment: Is it possible to do like a pop up window that can contains cancel and okay actions? (I know in iOS they have UIAlertController that supports the creation of a pop up window natively, but seems in Android making a "Toast message" is more popular)

Comment: @YanZhuang yes you can create an AlertDialog. Wait a while I'll post that code too. If my answer solved your issue please accept it as answer in the mean time.

Comment: @YanZhuang I have updated my code and this will now create an AlertDialog as per your needs. If your issue is solved then please accept my answer to let know others know that this is solved and upvote if you like. Thnks

Comment: Thank you very much for your method! This has been working very effectively in my app!